# JMeter, How to assert customer ID generated randomly and contain special character using Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, assertion, nsregularexpression

I have an API that contains a customer ID value, that is generated randomly and contains special character.

I need to assert this customer ID using Response Assertion, But due to the special characters , the comparison shows fail .

**Example:**
**API body:**
{Customer_ID : "rzrzlk@kad9$l11zr@zz9dr1"
}

**My response assertion:**
"data":[{"customer_id":"rzrzlk@kad9$l11zr@zz9dr1",

**Result:**
Assertion failed

I know I should user backslash , but when you dont know where to user it inside the values, it will be useless.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a backslash only if you're escaping regular expressions [meta characters](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html#meta_chars)

If you just need to ensure that response contains the given value you should use the following setup:

[image]

- `Contains` and `Matches` modes expect a regular expression
- `Equals` and `Substring` modes expect a plain text string

More information: [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-three-easy-steps)